# Yarn install --production --pure-lockfile | SyntaxError: Unexpected Token

Tags: installation, yarnpkg

I want to install PeerTube on my Server. 
But when I run `sudo -H -u peertube yarn install --production --pure-lockfile` the following message returns from the Server:

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This look like a common yarn error that require to reinstall nodejs from nodesource

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -

apt-get install -y nodejs

See https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6914